# Serialize IEnumerable with Json.NET with other properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class which Implements IEnumerable and another Interface IModel:

```
    public class Model : IEnumerable, IModel {
        private readonly List<string> list = new List<string> {"aa", "bb"};
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
            return this.list.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

When I call

```
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Model() { Name = "Test" });
```

Json.NET is only serializing the Elements of the List. The Result is:

```
    ["aa","bb"]
```

What do I have to do, that Json.NET will also serialize the Property Name?
Note: This is only a small Sample and I cannot change the original class because I am not the developer of the class.

Comment: This behaviour is pretty common in serializers - pretty sure that `XmlSerializer` works similarly, and protobuf-net does that *by default* (although can be flipped); generally, things should look *either* like a collection *or* like a leaf node - here the serializer is saying "that looks kinda like a collection to me - I'll treat it as a json array and iterate it"

Comment: Start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/1997232).

Comment: And how resulting json should look like? What name to use for property with array of items?